# More flexible privacy settings for the public and private profiles

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, profile-page, privacy

Is it possible to make the detailed job experience description available to the `Stack Overflow Careers` logged users only?

I need more flexible privacy settings for the public profile, e.g. my public profile in `SOC` will contain only a brief description of my job experience and the detailed information will be available only to logged users. In such way, I'll know, in the most of times, who is interesting my profile, like I can do it in `LinkedIn`.

The current functionality is going in «all or nothing» strategy and thus is problematic. It allows to you or completely expose your profile and thus any privacy settings in `LinkedIn` become useless (user can anonymously see your profile in `SOC`). Or completely hide profile for the search engines by making it private and this will significantly limit your potential auditory.

The bottom line, I want to be able to propose the enough information to interest someone, in other words, to propose a teaser, but if someone is really interested in my profile, he should «buy a ticket» — I would like to get more information about viewer and not to allow an anonymous full profile view. `LinkedIn` allows such policy, `Stack Overflow Careers` — currently not.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion here around three different settings (and it's possible I don't fully understand what scenario you're imagining where some people find your "teaser" profile).

The reason for the "public" setting on the profile is to enable you to send a link to your Stack Overflow Careers profile anywhere you would normally send a resumé. This could be a link from your website, in an application on another job board, anyplace where you'd need a resumé.

If you want greater discoverability, you can allow search engines to index your profile, too. If you want greater control over what information is available to whom, you can block search engines, which effectively means your public profile would only be seen by people who have the link.

The last piece of this is the most important to your request of forcing people to "buy a ticket". In addition to the public/private setting, there is an **Employer Searches & Messaging** setting on your profile settings page. If you choose "looking for a job" or "not looking, but open to being contacted," we'll show your profile in search results for paying customers who subscribe to our Candidate Search product. If you choose the "block all messages and searches" setting, your profile will not appear in search results for our customers. This is completely independent of whether your profile is public or private, though.

So I *believe* that these setting together provide what you're looking for. If you only want people viewing your profile if they've purchased access, set your profile to private, block it from being indexed by search engines, and set your messaging preference to "looking for a job" or "not looking, but open to being contacted".

I'm afraid we don't generally build Stack Overflow Careers profiles to optimize for compatibility with LinkedIn; we're perfectly okay with you having profiles on both, but it's unlikely that we'll build features and preferences to exactly match another site's.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Under the «teaser» profile I mean a brief of your experience without the detailed explanation of what exactly you did, e.g. the teaser will be something like: «Back and front end developer at %Company%», while the full profile will contain also the list of your responsibilities & accomplishments you achieved on this position. Under «buy a ticket» I mean the ability ***to see who visited*** your profile and do not allow the ***anonymous*** full profile review.

Comment: I understand what you mean by a teaser, @MikeB., but I'm not clear on who would be seeing that version of your profile and how. Are you just talking about if someone types your name into a search engine?

Comment: Yes. Suppose, John Smith has two identical profiles both, on `LI` and `SOC`. Now, the potential employer is interesting in John's profile and searches for it in search engine. He will get links to the both of these two profiles, but the `LI` will be limited, while `SOC` will be fully exposed. Of course, you can limit the indexing by `SE`, but then you limit your chance to be discovered by somebody relevant. The `LI` approach, IMHO, is optimal, from one side it allows to be discovered, from the other the profile holder can see, at least company name, if somebody interested in his full profile.